# Get email header and footer in phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I want to get email header and footer template in phtml file.

```
<!-- Here I want to send mail with header and footer template --> 
$body = "Some Data";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Set To Email');
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->setSubject('Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Set From Email');
$mail->setType('html');
$mail->send();
```

Comment: If you want to use in your custom module, create your own email template.

Comment: No I want to get default email header and footer , not from custom template.

Comment: yes for that also you need a template to pass this values for both header and footer.
Header :- {{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
Footer  :-  {{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}

Comment: {{template config_path="design/email/header"}} is used in blocks and cms pages but I want this same in phtml file.